# Running an external executable program with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, executable

I have an application on my PC, let's call it TurboApp.exe. After the app is launched, to run it you can either click on the run button in the app or simply press Ctrl+R. I want to perform the above steps using Python and I've got it working like below:

```
import os
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()

os.startfile(filename)
keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
keyboard.press('r')
keyboard.release('r')
keyboard.release(Key.ctrl)
```

The problem with the above code is the PC screen can't be locked while running it as the `keyboard` commands won't work and throw an error.

> pywintypes.error: (0, 'SetForegroundWindow', 'No error message is available')

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You would need to get a library that supports keyboard simulation with a locked screen, if such a thing is even possible. Unfortunately, that's out of scope for SO. That being said, I think that there is a software recommendation Stack Exchange somewhere.

Comment: You might have better luck here: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com. Your question seems well suited.